# Ideal data structure with OpenMP

Tags: c++, data-structures, openmp, parallel-processing

What is an ideal data structure in parallel programing, in my case OpenMP.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    if(table[i] == true)
        container.insert(i); // ?? what kind
}
```

In this example it might be simple if we use a table of similar size. What is a more general data structure for shared-memory parallel programing in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best not to rely on shared data structures at all (because you'll have to rely on locks at some point, which will slow things down).  Instead, have each thread write to its own structure, and coalesce the results once the parallel section has completed.

Comment: You are right. Sadly, OpenMPs own `reduction` only supports primitive types.

Comment: So each thread would have whatever data structure and the final result is collected. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

The array is the ideal data structure for parallel programming.

I don't share @Oli Charlesworth's reluctance to rely on shared data structures -- after all OpenMP is about shared-memory parallelisation and it provides the tools a programmer needs to ensure data safety.

Comment: In this particular case an array doesn't count, as the code is *collecting* some data (or reducing, as you want to call it). This selects some elements from the original array. For the array to work well, it has to have a pre-assigned elements to each working thread to avoid locks, wait states and race conditions, but in this case, how do you know how many elements the final array is going to have? How many elementso do you assign to each thread? Then, you have to allow a central repository to add each result, needing to lock the access to the structure, hurting performance.

Comment: So in the array case I would need a single large array and then a set of separate counters for each thread with no locks necessary?